# Woocommerce - Remove image filename on product image gallery (lightbox)

Tags: css, image, lightbox, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the image filename that appears above the image in the lightbox functionality on the single-product page.

My images have a terrible naming structure and it is very distracting to the user to see "IMG_1234.JPG".

Is there a setting in WooCommerce that will allow me to toggle this on and off? Or will I need to change the file by adding/removing code?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

If you use any woocommerce compatible template then you'll find a directory named "woocommerce" in your template folder.

If you can't find it then it'll be the `wp-contents/plugins/woocommerce/templates` directory. In that case your theme doesn't overwrite the default layout. Then you need to find `templates(or woocommerce)/single-product/product-image.php` file. Around line 21 you should find something as following-

```
$image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
```

add // infront of that line (comment that out) as follows-.

```
// $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
```

Now search for something `rel="prettyPhoto'` around in line 31. Remove `title="%s"` from that line where you find `rel="prettyPhoto'`.

Again find `product-thumbnails.php` in the same folder of the previous one. In around 40 you'll see something as follows like before-

```
$image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );
```

Comment this out adding two forward slashes(//) just like the previous one.
Now again in around line 42 search for something `prettyPhoto[product-gallery]` and when you find it look for `title="%s"` nearby and remove it like before.

This will remove the title form the lightbox picture viewer.

Instead of all these works you can simply use this following script inside your header.php file or anywhere you may find suitable-

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('a[rel*="prettyPhoto"]').attr('title','').find('img').attr('alt','');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: maksbd19, Thank you so much for responding! I have followed your directions very closely and have not had any luck. The outcome of your directions produces a image-less product. When I get the single-product page, the front-end does not display the main image for the product. Also, I did not have luck inserting the script you provided into my header.php file because I am not sure where to insert it. Is it simply anywhere after "<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>" ?? Thanks again, -Chris

Comment: you can insert this code before </head> tag in your header.php file. That workd for me.

Comment: No luck on my end again...
I inserted your code right after the opening <head> tag...

<head>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('a[rel*="prettyPhoto"]').attr('title','').find('img').attr('alt','');
    });
</script>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<title><?php woo_title(''); ?></title>


I am using the folowing: 

Wordpress 3.6.1
Mystile Theme 1.2.15
WooCommerce 2.0.14

Comment: can you provide me a chance to look at your project because i don't get it. its a silly problem and so do the solution. It should work, always working to mine!!!!