# Hide Woocommerce Lightbox Image Description

Tags: css, image, woocommerce, lightbox

as per description. How could I hide the description? I tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599580/woocommerce-remove-image-filename-on-product-image-gallery-lightbox) but it is not working. What could I try?

Other question: what is the ideal image size of the product? Should I make them all the same size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no code provided I'm just going to guess:

1. Get a Webkit browser (Google, Opera) or Firefox.
2. Right click on the image description and select "Inspect Element"
3. Find the class of the HTML element that holds the description (let's say it's .pp_description) and memorize it
4. Open your WordPress theme and find style.css
5. At the very bottom of the file write the following code:

   .pp_description {
       display: none!important;
   }

As for your second question - there is no "ideal image size of a product", do it however you like it.